# How to run a method using ./ instead of calling by Python3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I know the first bit of code is the declaration that's needed but I can't figure else what im needing.

Comment: Have you made the file executable?

Comment: Oh that's what it is. Just did now, working fine. Thanks khelwood.